# Magento 2 magento_swatch not working properly

Tags: magento2.1.0

- I have one configurable product with "**size**" and "**color**" attribute.
- I can see "**size**" and "color" both attribute in English store but in other stores like **dutch**, **Spanish**, **French** .. etc I can not see "size"
  attribute in category page or in product page or in the left navigation. I have set "size" attribute "global" so we can use in all
  store but it does not show on all store.

you can also check my attached screen shot.

so please help me for resolve this issue.